# Empty form when submitting with SpringMVC and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to edit data (checkboxes) in a table. But when I click on the submit button, the form in the controller is empty

I didn't find a example with thymeleaf so I adapted [this example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list)

I use a form object:

```
public class MyForm {
  private List<MyObj> data;
  // ...
}
```

The controller with the two methods (GET and POST):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editGet(Model model) {
  MyForm form = new MyForm(data);
  model.addAttribute("myForm", form);
  return "editPage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editPost(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm, Model model) {
 // here myForm.getData() is empty
}
```

And my html:

```
<form th:action="@{/edit/save}" th:object="${myForm}" method="POST">
  <table>
    <thead>....</thead>
      <tbody th:each="myObj : *{data}" th:remove="tag">
        <tr>
          <td><span th:text="${myObj.name}"></span></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${myObj.isOK}"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit">Save</input>
</form>
```

What did I forget?

Comment: I think you need 'th:value' and 'name' in your input filed.
Also I'm using <form:form> tag and one param ot this tag is 'modelAttribute'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following syntax :

```
<tr th:each="myObj, rowStat : *{data}">
```

and then set the input fields using :

```
th:field="*{data[__${rowStat}.index}__].myField}"
```

That will bind your MyForm with the input data.

More examples can be found here 
[Thymeleaf and forms](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/I-have-problem-in-binding-the-list-of-objects-contained-inside-a-object-on-the-form-using-thymeleaf-td3525038.html)